# How to filter DataFrame rows by list of conditions simultaneously on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter, multiple-columns

I have a DataFrame where I want to filter rows appling a list of condition applicable simultaneously on two columns. For example:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':['Y','Y','Y','Z','Z'],'B':[1,2,2,3,4],'C':[100,200,234,358,4243]})
   A  B     C
0  Y  1   100
1  Y  2   200
2  Y  2   234
3  Z  3   358
4  Z  4  4243
filter_on=[('Y',2),('Z',4)]
```

When filtering where *A* and *B* have any of the couple of values at *filter_on* , I should get following DataFrame:

```
   A  B     C
1  Y  2   200
2  Y  2   234
4  Z  4  4243
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `isin` after convert to `tuple`

```
out = df[df[['A','B']].apply(tuple,1).isin(filter_on)].copy()
   A  B     C
1  Y  2   200
2  Y  2   234
4  Z  4  4243
```

Answer (score 3):

You could build a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) from the columns and use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) to compute the mask, as follows:

```
mask = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['A'], df['B']]).isin(filter_on)
print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
   A  B     C
1  Y  2   200
2  Y  2   234
4  Z  4  4243
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.iloc[[i for  i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(data.A, data.B)) if (a,b) in filter_on]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this succinct `set_index` and `Index.isin` based solution?

```
df[df.set_index(['A', 'B']).index.isin(filter_on)]

   A  B     C
1  Y  2   200
2  Y  2   234
4  Z  4  4243
```